# "you need a C compiler to build uWSGI" - but gcc is present

Tags: software-installation, python, gcc, uwsgi

I get the following error:

```
~$ sudo apt install build-essential python2.7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
python2.7-dev is already the newest version (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
~$ gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
~$ pip install uwsgi==1.9.20 --index-url=http://192.168.1.200/pypackages/simple/ --trusted-host 192.168.1.200
Collecting uwsgi==1.9.20
  Downloading http://192.168.1.200/pypackages/simple/uwsgi/uwsgi-1.9.20.tar.gz (731kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 737kB 12.1MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-u0AKpd/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp63xyFzpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-u0AKpd/uwsgi/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
      distclass=uWSGIDistribution,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 240, in run
      self.run_command('install')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-u0AKpd/uwsgi/setup.py", line 71, in run
      conf = uc.uConf(get_profile())
    File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 627, in __init__
      raise Exception("you need a C compiler to build uWSGI")
  Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI
```

The error says I do not have a C compiler but gcc is installed.

Comment: `uwsgi` is already in the repositories, have you considered just installing `uwsgi` that way and then its plugins similarly?

Comment: Hi, yes I will try that - are there any differences I need to be aware of? The only one I've found is that I need to pass `--plugin=python` to my uwsgi command.
I'm still curious as to why it thinks I don't have a C compiler though...

Comment: Yeah not sure about why it's doing that either, but just having `gcc` alone doesn't mean it is a functioning compiler :P

Answer (score 1):

`uwsgi` is already in the repositories.  It might not be version 1.9.20 but it should still work for your needs (and is basically the same `uwsgi` from PyPI except precompiled and installable).

For installing it, and its Python 3 plugin, just run:

```
sudo apt install uwsgi uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

This will install `uwsgi` and the Python 3 plugin.  You can then execute `uwsgi --plugin=python3 ...` as normal for running it directly.

This said, if you don't want to run things yourself manually (though you may need to in some cases), you can also set up `uwsgi` configuiration files in `/etc/uwsgi/*.ini` and then start those services with `sudo systemctl stop uwsgi && sudo systemctl start uwsgi` and it'll run daemon-ized automatically.  Documentation on that, however, is in uwsgi's documentation, and is too complex and in-depth for me to copy here.  I use this to run three APIs for my employer on their infrastructure that're UWSGI based and have data passed into them from web endpoints authorized to access the API points, and it works pretty effectively.